# drupal jQuery 1.4 on specific pages

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-modules

I'm looking for a way to force drupal to use 1.4 on specific pages.

This is the same as this old question: [drupal jQuery 1.4 on specific pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842792/drupal-jquery-1-4-on-specific-pages)

It look me a while to try the answer which I marked correct. But because I'm new to module dev overall I couldn't figure it out based on the answer.

The code from that answer looked like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme_registry_alter().
 * Based on the jquery_update module.
 *
 * Make this page preprocess function runs *last*,
 * so that a theme can't call drupal_get_js().
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['page'])) {
    // See if our preprocess function is loaded, if so remove it.
    if ($key = array_search('MYMODULE_preprocess_page', 
      $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'])) {
      unset($theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][$key]);
    }
    // Now add it on at the end of the array so that it runs last.
    $theme_registry['page']['preprocess functions'][] = 'MYMODULE_preprocess_page';
  } 
}

/**
 * Implementation of moduleName_preprocess_hook().
 * Based on the jquery_update module functions.  *
 * Strips out JS and CSS for a path.
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables, $arg = 'my_page', $delta=0) {

  // I needed a one hit wonder. Can be altered to use function arguments
  // to increase it's flexibility.
  if(arg($delta) == $arg) {
    $scripts = drupal_add_js();
    $css = drupal_add_css();
    // Only do this for pages that have JavaScript on them.
    if (!empty($variables['scripts'])) {
      $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_menu');
      unset($scripts['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.js']);
      $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js('header', $scripts);
    }
    // Similar process for CSS but there are 2 Css realted variables.
    //  $variables['css'] and $variables['styles'] are both used.
    if (!empty($variables['css'])) {
      $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_menu');
      unset($css['all']['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.css']);
      unset($css['all']['module'][$path . '/admin_menu.color.css']);
      $variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
    }
  }
}
```

I need the jquery_update 1.3.2 to be unset on the node-types of 'blog' and 'video'. Can someone help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `MYMODULE_preprocess_page` function, the $scripts variable contains an array with the information about all JavaScript that will be added to the page.

If you want to remove a JS file from the page, you should remove its entry from the $scripts array (and then update $variables['scripts']). That's what the `unset` function is doing .

If the jQuery you're trying to remove is the one that's shipped with Drupal, you can remove it with:

```
unset($scripts['core']['misc/jquery.js']);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to `print_r` the $scripts var in order to find the entry you need to remove.

Comment: How do you check for content type so you know where to unset?

Right now it works via arg.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it's the right way, but I'd do it by querying the 'node' table for the 'type' field, based on the nid (from $_GET['q']).